# c++ for loop syntax difference

Tags: c++, for-loop

CLion linter suggests to change the traditional for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
        auto object = objects[i];
        ...
    }
```

To the range-based for each loop(since c++11):

```
for (auto & object : objects) {
        ...
    }
```

Are this syntax the exact same? I would argue no, as I get undefined behavior/crash in my more complex programs at least. Specifically when utilizing a vector of `shared_ptr`.

Are there any reason to why this would happen?

Comment: With no code to show, who can say? The two for loops are not *exactly* the same, though. Your 'manual' loop makes a copy, and the range-based for loop references each element.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)` sets you up to have integer overflow, so I would avoid using that.

Comment: Your two examples are not equivalent since one takes `object` by reference and the other by value.
Otherwise, they would be equivalent, though the range-based for loop is better for readability if you don't need the index and it's also less error prone.

Comment: If you change the first example to use `auto & object = objects[i];` the two are very similar. Functionally there are some subtle differences. There are some things you can do in the first version you can't do in the second, like add elements to `objects` in the loop body. Though the second form is preferred if you don't need to do anything that only the first form allows. Note that the first form only works for random access containers like `std::vector`. That kind of loop won't work for `std::map` or `std::list` for example.

Comment: Change `auto object = objects[i];` to `auto &object = objects[i];`, or change `for (auto & object : objects)` to `for (auto object : objects)`, then the two loops will be functionally identical in this case (assuming the loop body doesn't need `i` for anything else).

Comment: *"Are there any reason to why this would happen?"* -- to explain why your code crashes, we would need the code that crashes. (See if you can reduce your complex program down to a [mre] that consists of little more than your loop, where your loop's body is kept as short as will reproduce the crash.)

Comment: *"Are this syntax the exact same?"* -- if this really is your main question, you might want to read [range-based for loop @ cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). It can be a tough read if you're not used to the documentation style, though. (Sorry, I do not have time to apply it to your code at the moment. You might want to try applying it; this might be an educational experience for you.)

Answer (score 0):

SO, in my case the main difference is displayed when **modifying** the vector while iterating it. In this case the range based for-loop will make the program crash, but the integer based for-loop will continue to work! Thanks for the answers!